# Call controller method from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a button which change the "active" state. First, it loads the status from the server

```
<button active="data.active" ng-click="changeStatus()"></button>
```

directive code:

```
app.directive('active', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'whatever.html',
    scope: {
        active: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
        $scope.changeStatus = function() {
            // Actually I'm doing this, it works fine
            var value = !$scope.active;

            $scope.$parent.MethodWhoChangesState(value, function(response) {
                // I need to change the button state here
            });
        }
    }
  }
})
```

It works but I think I'm not respecting the "angular's rules"...

Is there a better way?

Comment: You should pass your function via attribute and bind it to scope using `&`

Comment: always good to assess if you really need an isolated scope also. If not, your directive would already be in parent scope

Comment: @charlietfl If he don't create new scope with attr biding, then he will need to double bind by himself.

Comment: @jcubic why is that? Just because you have directive it doesn't lose binding if using parent scope

Comment: @charlietfl if he need to use paramter `active="data.active"` he shouldn't just bind to parent scope for `data.active` because it may change, it's like a function with global variable. What if he will need to use a filter? He should use attribute for this as he did. Ad fastest way to bind to attribute is to use isolated scope with `=`.

Comment: @jcubic and many people get caught using isolated scopes when they don't need them also. I didn't say to get rid of it, I said it's always good to assess if it is needed. For example a directive used inside ng-repeat often doesn't need it simply because it's parent is already an isolated scope

Comment: But if I don't use isolated scope, which is the best way to pass an object? via attributes and do angular.fromJson(attr.myobject) ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you just have to update your $scope variable within your click handler. If you need to handle the case when the 'active' state changes, you can set up a $watch:

```
app.directive('active', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'whatever.html',
    scope: {
        active: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

        // if you need to run custom code whenever the 'active' state changes
        // you can set up a $watch   
        $scope.$watch('active', function(isActive) {
              if(isActive) {
                  ...
              }
              else {
                  ...
              }
        });

        $scope.changeStatus = function() {

            $scope.active = !$scope.active;
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I need to call a function of the $parent scope, in addition, If I put the this call within in the $watch, I think it would execute when the directive is rendered at the first time.